# Can I remove event.persist() if the event is not used in the handler?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Someone else wrote a React UI with several event handlers beginning with `event.persist()`. If I understand correctly the `persist()` function, it is needed to prevent React from recycling the `event` variable during the execution of the event handler. However, the `event` variable is not used in this handler function: I suspect it's a leftover of copypasting code from elsewhere.

Can I safely remove the call to `event.persist()` if the `event` variable is never used in the handler function?

Comment: Rule #1 - if you don't know what something does, don't touch it ;). The answer to your question might be in the original commits/PRs if you're using git or similar, of course.

Comment: @AdamJenkins That's why I'm asking :D As to the Git history, of course there is a commit with a comment, and the explanation is apparently "refactoring".

Comment: What version of react are you using? Asking because in version 17 event.persist is a noop

Comment: @AdamJenkins It's React 17.0.2. Nice to know, thank you!

Comment: Check the note on [this page](https://legacy.reactjs.org/docs/events.html)  about event.persist and react 17